# ¿Es común usar "asumir" con el significado de "suponer"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

En textos matemáticos o físicos en inglés, es común el uso del verbo *to assume* con el significado de "dar algo por supuesto":

- To calculate the trajectory of the throw, we have assumed that the projectile is only affected by the gravity of the Earth.

Siempre he pensado que el equivalente español era *asumir*. Es decir, hasta ahora, yo habría traducido esta frase así:

- Para calcular la trayectoria del lanzamiento, hemos asumido que el proyectil solo es afectado por la gravedad de la Tierra.

Sin embargo, hoy me ha sorprendido ver que la definición de [asumir](https://dle.rae.es/asumir) en el DLE no parece incluir este significado:

> 1. tr. Atraer a sí, tomar para sí.
> 2. tr. Hacerse cargo, responsabilizarse de algo, aceptarlo.
> 3. tr. Adquirir, tomar una forma mayor.

Parece que la traducción correcta usaría el verbo "suponer". Sin embargo, una [búsqueda en Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=asumir%20matematicas&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) me dice que no soy el único que comete este "error".

¿Es correcto el uso de "asumir" con el significado de "suponer" en textos científicos?

¿Es común el uso de "asumir" por "suponer" en el habla cotidiana en alguna región?

Comment: Aqui: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/which-verb-should-be-used-to-assume-something  puedes encontrar la respuesta.

Comment: Vaya, no sé cómo he podido no encontrar esa pregunta (aunque no es que el buscador de aquí me lo haya puesto fácil...) . Es curioso que el DLE siga sin incluir este significado, visto lo extendido que está. Voto para cerrar la pregunta como duplicado, parece que no puedo hacerlo unilateralmente con mis propias preguntas...

Comment: Voy a votar por cerrar también (pero sigo con la opinión de que "asumir el cargo" está bien, y "asumir que una solución de la ecuación existe" está mal, a pesar de las respuestas que se aportaron en esa página).

Comment: @aparente001 un problema es que "suppose" y "assume" tienen significados distintos en matemáticas. "Suppose" introduce hipótesis que luego pueden ser refutadas ("Suppose there is a finite amount of primes [...]  We arrive at a contradiction, so we conclude that there is not a finite amount of primes". Por otro lado, "assume" ("We assume that the Moon's gravity does not affect our object") significa "resolvemos una versión simplificada del problema en la que ignoramos este efecto". Una posible traducción sería "dar por sentado", pero supongo que se prefiere "asumir" porque es más corto.

Comment: @wimi - Interesante lo que dices.  Pero me inclino por pensar que son diferencias de costumbre, más que nada.  Si comparáramos *supposition* y *assumption* -- ¿mantendrías todavía que hay una diferencia estricta?

Comment: @aparente001 en textos matemáticos sí, la diferencia es la misma. En esas comunidades (en las que el lenguaje debe ser muy preciso), las costumbres se convierten rápidamente en "obligación". De hecho, lo que me llevó a escribir esta pregunta es que intenté buscar una traducción de "assumption" y me di cuenta que ni siquiera mi uso de "asumir" era correcto.

Comment: @wimi - *me di cuenta que ni siquiera mi uso de "asumir" era correcto* -- ¿cómo?  Creí que me estabas describiendo lo que has observado en tus estudios e investigaciones.

Comment: @aparente001 mis estudios e investigaciones son en inglés. Queriendo explicar uno de ellos en español, me di cuenta de que mi uso de "asumir" en español no es correcto según la RAE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103263/discussion-between-aparente001-and-wimi).